# What is the suit used by Ichimatsu Kohina?

Tags: costume, gugure-kokkuri-san

Does this type of suit have a name? Is it real or only made in-universe? It's from the anime [繰れ! コックリさん /Repeat! Kokkurisan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugure!_Kokkuri-san), ep 10.

[image: anime girl with rectangle eyes sniffing a leaf]
[image: anime girl and tiny fox on a forest path]
[image: from left to right, tiny fox wearring a bell, anime girl, and some other animal]

Close-up on the boots:

[image: anime girl boots]

Comment: They appear to be dressed as a haystack

Comment: If I remember correctly this is also shown in Princess Mononoke - Ashitaka wears it in a few scenes

Comment: Its seems so, but if these are ,they are kinda different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is some kind of Mino (蓑), a traditional Japanese garment, a raincoat made out of straw.

[image: Mino]
[image: Straw boots]

<sub>a picture of Warōzu [草鞋](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%8D%89%E9%9E%8B), a straw boots too.</sub>

Comment: And they even come with darling little hats made of straw; https://muza-chan.net/aj/poze-weblog4/straw-raincoat-boso-no-mura-open-air.jpg

Comment: And I was thinking this is for the sake of the character only.

Comment: @valorum notice a cute little straw boots too (from middle picture).

Comment: @Oni;Thats one of the points that make me wonder if these are reall or no, this seems too kawaii to be real.

Comment: @Oni I try to made a close up to the boots

Comment: Googling found a page with images of real straw boots of that nature https://tokaido.wordpress.com/2007/12/10/japanese-straw-boots-hand-made-traditional-footwear/ (It appears to be a WP site that linked to an eBay storefront where one could buy the items, but the store links appear to all be dead. With the store defunct anyway, hopefully posting URL of a commerce-related page is ok. If not: Mods feel free to delete this comment.) See also https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g298172-d1755588-i25088153-Nihon_Minkaen_Japan_Open_Air_Folk_House_Museum-Kawasaki_Kanagawa_Prefectu.html